# How to display different text for a section's entry in the table of contents in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, context, context-mkiv

In LaTeX, one can display different text in the table of contents, than what appears in the document, for `part`, `chapter`, and `section` titles using this:

```
\part[This text will appear in the table of contents]{This text will appear in the document}
```

- How can this be achieved in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\start … \stop` environments, with `title` and `list` keys.

```
\starttext
\completecontent

\startsection[title={This text will appear in the document}, list={This text will appear in the table of contents}]
text
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `\section[...]{...}` command.

The argument within `[...]` becomes the text shown in a `\tableofcontents`

The title within `{...}` is shown within the document.

Comment: That syntax works for LaTeX but not for ConTeXt. `\tableofcontents` is not a valid command in ConTeXt.